# Axios, Pinia - based URL is not used and reuqest isn't sent to server

Tags: axios, vuejs3, pinia

I have following Axios configuration:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {useMainStore} from "@/store/main";

const mainStore = useMainStore()

const axiosClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://api.servant.test/',
})

axiosClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${mainStore.token}`
    return config
})

export default axiosClient
```

And in my Pinia store I have following:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axiosClient from '@/router/index'

export const useMainStore = defineStore('main', {
    id: 'main',
    state: () =>
    {
        return {
            userData: {},
            token: sessionStorage.getItem('TOKEN'),
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async login(data) {
            try {
                this.userData = axiosClient.post('login',{data})
            } catch (error)
            {
                return error
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The **login** action is working (error isn't thrown) but the post request isn't send to the server. It is not using network request at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `error isn't thrown` doesn't really means that the login action is working.
maybe the action is not called at all . 
can yoou check that it's really called ?

Comment: also you should probably add an `await` before `axiosClient.post`

Comment: the issue probably is that `this.userData = axiosClient.post` results in `this.userData` being a Promise - not sure why that code is inside an `async` function that never uses `await` - probably a typo